# Sorting records based on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a dealers tables with following columns

```
dealer_name    is_iso    is_gst    is_approved
```

& need to display dealers records in following order

```
dealers with all columns set should appear first,
then dealers with iso & gst,
then with iso & verified,
then with gst & verified,
then with iso,
then with gst
```

data in dealers table is like

```
dealer_name     is_iso  is_gst  Is_approved
A               1       1       1
B               1       0       1
C               1       0       0
D               0       1       0
E               1       1       0
F               0       1       1
G               1       0       0
G               1       1       1
```

Currently, I am using CASE WHEN ( answer below ) to achieve this & need to know if there is better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE  
        WHEN (typeA = 1 and typeB = 1 and isISO = 1)  THEN 6
        WHEN (typeA = 1 and typeB = 1 and isISO = 0)  THEN 5
        WHEN (typeA = 1 and typeB = 0 and isISO = 1)  THEN 4
        WHEN (typeA = 0 and typeB = 1 and isISO = 1)  THEN 3
        WHEN (typeA = 1 and typeB = 0 and isISO = 0)  THEN 2
        WHEN (typeA = 0 and typeB = 1 and isISO = 0)  THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as dealer_order
FROM
    dealers 
ORDER BY
    dealer_order desc
```